# Discord.js - Give role a all channel

Tags: discord.js

Hello I would like to create an order (`! Giverole`) so that it gives the roles (mute) to all the channels of the server or to be made the order.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "giverole")) {

var mute_role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name == 'mute', {READ_MESSAGES: true, SEND_MESSAGES: false})

if (!mute_role) return message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, role not found`)

message.guild.channels.overwritePermissions(channel => channel.addRole(mute_role));


                      var lock_embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                      .setColor("#ffad33")
                      .setDescription(":lock: **Salon bloqué pour les gens mute**")

                      message.channel.send(lock_embed)
```

thank you in advance

Comment: And what are you asking for?

Comment: Hello, roles can only be given to members of a server, and this can be done through the `GuildMember#addRole` method. They cannot be given to channels. As for the other part of your question, I’m afraid I don’t know what you mean by “to be made the order”. You can add some form of “mute” functionality by creating something like a “Muted” role in the server, setting up permissions for that role for the server &/or its sections/channels such that those with the role cannot send messages, then make the bot give specific server members that role through a command like `!tempmute User#1234`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the fist - try always get role with role ID, its more safely.
If I understand your question correctly and you need a certain role on all channels to establish certain rights. So you can use this code.

````js
    client.on('message', message => {
        if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "giverole")) {
            let muteRole = message.guild.roles.get('ROLEID')

            if (!muteRole) return message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, role not found`)

            message.guild.channels.map(channel => {
                if(channel.type === 'text') {
                    channel.overwritePermissions(muteRole, {
                        VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
                        SEND_MESSAGES: false
                    })
                     .then(console.log)
                     .catch(console.log);
                }
            })


            let lock_embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor("#ffad33")
            .setDescription(":lock: **Salon bloqué pour les gens mute**")
            message.channel.send(lock_embed)
        }

    })
    ```
````